# Refactoring condition for Math absolute

Tags: javascript

Currently trying to refactor my code down to make it more simple and DRY, is there a way to combine `Math.absolute` together so that the `<= 1` and `Math.abs()` does not keep repeating?

```
Math.abs(rowIndex - nodeRowIndex) <= 1 && Math.abs(colIndex - nodeColIndex) <= 1
```

Edited: adding this in in case it makes more sense. Currently trying to refactor my code block down and see that the <= 1 and Math.abs are repeating

```html
/*
* This function finds the neighbor of a given node's coordinate in a 2D array graph
* and returns the valid neighbor found within it 
*
* @param {array} node; e.g. [2, 0]
* @param {array} matrix; e.g. [[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 9], [5, 7, 6]] 
* @return {array} valid array of node's neighbors
*/
function findNeighbors(node, matrix) {
    
    // create array to store neighbors
    const neighbors = [];

    // destructure node row and node column index for easier usage
    const [nodeRowIndex, nodeColIndex] = node;

    // get the node value to be use for comparison with each matrix's value and cell information
    const nodeVal = matrix[nodeRowIndex][nodeColIndex];

    // in each row, get the row value and row index...
    matrix.map((currRow, rowIndex) =>
        // in each column, get the column value and column index...
        currRow.map((currCellVal, colIndex) => 
            // if the row index and column index is less than or equal to 1 difference
            // between the node's row/col index
            Math.abs(rowIndex - nodeRowIndex) <= 1 && Math.abs(colIndex - nodeColIndex) <= 1
                // AND if the current cell value is only 1 difference than the node's value then...
                && Math.abs(currCellVal - nodeVal) <= 1 && 
                    // ALSO check if the current row and column index is not the same as the node's
                    // row and column index
                    !(rowIndex === nodeRowIndex && colIndex === nodeColIndex) ? 
                    
                    // if passed all checks, push the current row and column into neighbors
                    // otherwise, do nothing
                    neighbors.push([rowIndex, colIndex]) : ""
        ) // end currRow map
    ); // end matrix map

    // return the neighbors thereafter
    return neighbors;
} // end findNeighbor function
```

Comment: No. If you want to avoid the duplication, create a helper function, but you still have to call it twice.

Comment: For two conditions, i wouldn't recommend any change here. If you get more, there are options (e.g. `[/*...*/].every(e => e <= 1)`, but this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: As noted by @Bergi, May be add a function: `const oneDiff = (a, b) =>  Math.abs(a - b) <= 1;` Then, you call that in your condition like so: `.... oneDiff(rowIndex, nodeRowIndex) && oneDiff(colIndex, nodeColIndex) && oneDiff(currCellVal, nodeVal) && .....`. Or, you could include @ASDFGerte as well like so: `.... [[rowIndex, nodeRowIndex], [colIndex, nodeColIndex], [currCellVal, nodeVal]].every(([a, b]) => oneDiff(a, b)) && ....`